# Соединение двух частей сообщения. Питон, VkApi

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, случайные-числа

Часть кода:

```
                    if event.text == "/бросок" or event.text == "/Бросок":
                        if event.from_chat:
                            A1 = random.randint(1, 6)
                            A2 = random.randint(1, 6)
                            vk.messages.send(
                            chat_id=event.chat_id,
                            random_id=get_random_id(),
                            message=A1+A2,
                            reply_to=event.message_id
                    )
```

Вывод: *число от 2 до 12*
Необходимо сделать так, чтоб вывод был (1число + 2число) = результат двух чисел.
Буду благодарен

Comment: `message='{} + {} = {}'.format(A1, A2, A1+A2)`

Comment: @alexjust, благодарствую! Как раз разузнаю что либо по поводу .format!
И, если вам хочется, напишите это в ответ, дабы повысить ваш рейтинг

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как написал @alex just в комментариях, ответ таков:

message='({} + {}) = {}'.format(A1, A2, A1+A2),

Благодаря ему, вывод стал тем, каким ожидался.